# Making a phone call in an iOS application depending on Time of Day

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm currently developing my own iOS application that makes a phone call from the press of a button. I'd like to make it so the button calls a different number depending on the time of day. My idea is to differentiate the numbers by UTC, since local time will depend on where the device is. For example, if it is between 00:01 and 08:00, then call 1234567. If it is between 08:01 and 16:00 UTC, then call 7654321.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

typealias WorkingTime = (start: NSDate, end: NSDate)
typealias TelephoneNumber = String

enum Regions {
    case Americas
    case EMEA
    case APAC

    func serviceDeskNumberForRegion(region: Regions) -> TelephoneNumber {
        switch self {
        case .Americas:
            return "00112341234"
        case .EMEA:
            return "12345678976543"
        case .APAC:
            return "3245678908"
        }
    }
}


//this is to create the dates from string
let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"



//we're hardcoding....
struct WorkingTimesForRegion {
    static let AmericanWorkingTimes = (start: dateformatter.dateFromString("00:01")!, end: dateformatter.dateFromString("08:00")!)
    static let EMEAWorkingTimes = (start: dateformatter.dateFromString("08:01")!, end: dateformatter.dateFromString("16:00")!)
    static let APACWorkingTimes = (start: dateformatter.dateFromString("16:01")!, end: dateformatter.dateFromString("00:00")!)

    static func regionForTime(time: NSDate) -> Regions {
        //
        //here I should use the nscalendar to make sure all times are represented on the same timezones, like UTC. Not sure how to go about this.
        //


        //here I probably need to check both end and start 
        //a switch case would've been more elegant here but I don't see how to build it at the moment
        //an option I would explore is using NSRange as they make sense in principle and can be used in switch statements.
        //but I don't know if you can create ranges of dates ...
        if time.compare(WorkingTimesForRegion.AmericanWorkingTimes.end) == .OrderedAscending {
            return .Americas
        } else if time.compare(WorkingTimesForRegion.EMEAWorkingTimes.end) == .OrderedAscending {
            return .EMEA
        } else if time.compare(WorkingTimesForRegion.EMEAWorkingTimes.end) == .OrderedAscending {
            return .APAC
        }
        //just in case
        return .EMEA
    }
}


func serviceDeskForTime(time: NSDate) -> TelephoneNumber {
    let serviceDeskInCharge = WorkingTimesForRegion.regionForTime(time)
    return serviceDeskInCharge.serviceDeskNumberForRegion(serviceDeskInCharge)
}


//see if it works
serviceDeskForTime(dateformatter.dateFromString("05:00")!)


func call() -> Bool {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: "tel://123456765") else { return false }
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
    return false
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You stated your goal, but not what specific problem you are having achieving that goal. Where are you stuck, **specifically**?

Comment: Also, why try to convert from time of day the app is used to a region, why not ask for the region, use the GPS / IP address ?

Comment: Sorry. I'm getting the error "Struct declaration cannot close over value 'dateformatter' defined in outerscope" in the struct WorkingTimesForRegion. Specifically, in each of the "static let" lines.

Comment: @Wain I don't want the local time of the device. I want a universal time where only certain numbers can be called. The idea is that certain 'help desks' are open during certain hours, and to route the user to correct help desk given a universal time.